403 Forbidden Error When Attempting to Log In to Amazon ECR Public Using AWS CLI
I’m trying to log in to Amazon ECR Public to push Docker images from the AWS CLI on an EC2 instance (Ohio region, us-east-2). I've configured my credentials with full access to ECR and followed the necessary steps to log in to the public ECR registry.
When I run the following command:
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin public.ecr.aws/g0n5y2m3
I get this error:
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://public.ecr.aws/v2/ failed with status: 403 Forbidden 
aws-cli/1.18.69

Verified that my credentials are properly set up in ~/.aws/credentials.
Confirmed that my IAM user has both AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess and AmazonElasticContainerRegistryPublicFullAccess policies attached.
Ensured that I am in the correct region (us-east-2).

What could be causing this 403 Forbidden error when trying to log in to a public ECR repository? Is there anything additional I need to configure to access ECR Public from the CLI?

Try aws ecr-public get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin public.ecr.aws. ("When authenticating to a public registry, always authenticate to the us-east-1 Region when using the AWS CLI.") More details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/public/public-registry-auth.html

The --region parameter in aws ecr get-login-password isn’t necessary for public ECR in most cases. You might try without it:
aws ecr-public get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin public.ecr.aws

also, You mentioned using aws-cli/1.18.69, which is an older version. Public ECR support and certain features require at least AWS CLI version 2.x.
